# Why public class can't extend private class?

Tags: kotlin

I have a following class hierarchy:

```
interface Repository

// This class contains some common stuff for LocalRepository and RemoteRepository. I'm never going to use this class outside this file, so I make it private
private abstract  class BasicRepositoryImpl

// these classes are designed to be instantiated in other files    
class LocalRepository : BasicRepositoryImpl(), Repository // error

class RemoteRepository : BasicRepositoryImpl(), Repository // error
```

But I get the following error:

> Subclass effective visibility 'public' should be the same or less
>   permissive than its superclass effective visibility 'private'

I don't want to use `BasicRepositoryImpl` anywhere else, so it's declared `private`, and I want to use `LocalRepository` and `RemoteRepository` in other files like this:

```
class Presenter(val repo: Repository)

val p = Presenter(LocalRepository())
```

But that error prevents me to create such a hierarchy. Why? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class and its ancestors must **all** be accessible from the using class.  Otherwise it would be an violation when loading the ancestor class, not just calling its methods or using its functionality.  Kotlin is very clean and clear about this in all cases where accessibility is present.

Opening it up a little would allow things that could cause real JVM access violations later, like an `inline` function in the public class, inlined into another class, calling the private non accessible *something* of the ancestor.  There are many holes you aren't considering if you feel it is ok to do a mixed model of accessibility like this.  The matrix of considerations is larger than only the desire to hide some classes from instantiation.

With the class being abstract, it cannot be used directly other than as an ancestor, so you have some protection already.  If you want to block use as an  ancestor outside of your module, make its constructor `private` or `internal` and that will solve that problem:

```
abstract class BasicRepositoryImpl private constructor() { ... }
```

Now you have protected direct instantiation (`abstract`) or use as a base class (by using `abstract` and private constructors) so the last things to do is give it a good name like `AbstractBaseRepository` and people will by convention leave it alone.

If you want to discuss *"why"* this is the design decision, or technical limitation, or protective rule ... then try the [discussion forums](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/), a feature or language change suggestion in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com).  But beware things are not as simple as they first appear to be.  These rules are there for reasons (*even if other languages dangerously allow*).

Answer (score 0):

**only make it abstract class**

*Definition:*
An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

[A comment from Roman Elizarov](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-does-kotlin-prohibit-exposing-restricted-visibility-types/7047/6) suggests to me that this restriction is largely about the possibility that the author of the `internal` class might not be in the frame of mind of designing a `public` class and thus might end up exposing something accidentally.

He also notes that there are some downsides to this restriction, and he links to [his feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22396) to allow this *if* the `internal` class is annotated with `@PublishedApi`. That seems like a nice compromise to me, but I don't get the impression that the feature is coming anytime soon.