# Why can't we have public typealiases from private expanded types?

Tags: kotlin

If I try this:

```
sealed class Attributes

data class Attributes1(
    val prop1: String
) : Attributes()

private data class IMyType<A>(
    val attributes: A
) where A: Attributes

typealias MyType1 = IMyType<Attributes1>
```

...I get the error: **'public' typealias exposes 'private' in expanded type IMyType**.

What is/are the reason(s) for preventing this?

*Note: Using Kotlin 1.1.4*

**Edit 1**

I understand what typealiases are and I understand the implications of the restrictions in place.

What I'm asking is why those restrictions need to be there.

If you consider my example code... I want `MyType1` (and maybe others) to be accessible outside of this file, but I don't want the raw/generic `IMyType` to be used outside of this file.

Is that not a legitimate use case?

Answer (score 2):

By definition [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) is to provide an alternative name for the existing type. So you can't promoting the visibility for the existing type by typealias.

From the [grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#typeAlias) of the typealias, if you want to use typealias in your code, you must make sure the visibility of the typealias is lower or equals than the visibility of the existing type. for example:

```
internal class Bar

private typealias PrivateFoo = Bar

internal typealias InternalFoo = Bar

//v--- error
public typealias PublicFoo = Bar
```

Comment: @pleasedesktop hi, this is because I you try to expose a class through `typealias` that the client can't to see and use.

Comment: The client will be able to see it, but they wouldn't be able to use it, which is exactly the behaviour I'm after. My expanded type is generic, but I don't want to expose the generic, I want to expose non-generics, via typealiases.

Comment: @pleasedesktop the kotlin code can't see the class except in the same file if the visibility is [private](https://hyp.is/SzkBZJK4Eee-KNMAFB9biw/kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html). you shouldn't cheated by your eye. however, you can see kotlin `private` classes in the same package in java code, this is because java can't use `private` keyword at the top level classes, you can try it in java and see the different. sorry, highlight the wrong location, fix it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the type alias should be the same or more restricted as the corresponding type.

When you declare `IMyType` as `private` in your file, `IMyType` is a file-private class which can be accessed only within that kotlin file. If you declare the public type alias `MyType1` for `IMyType`, then it is meaningless for `IMyType` to be private since `MyType1` can be access everywhere. So, it is forbidden.

From [Kotlin's doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html):

> **Type aliases do not introduce new types.** They are equivalent to the corresponding underlying types. When you add typealias `Predicate<T>` and use `Predicate<Int>` in your code, the Kotlin compiler always expand it to `(Int) -> Boolean`.

The main purpose of having `typealias` is to provide alternative name for existing types. In your case, both `IMyType` and `MyType1` refer to the same class. You cannot access `IMyType` through `MyType1` outside the file since `IMyType` intends to be private.

Example to show new type is not introduced:

```
//Kotlin code
fun acceptMyType1(type: MyType1) {}

//Decompiled code, MyType1 is not used
public static final void acceptMyType1(@NotNull IMyType type) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(type, "type");
}
```

<sub>Sidetracked problem: You cannot [expose a private super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460253/why-public-class-cant-extend-private-class) through a public sub class also.</sub>

Comment: @pleasedesktop They are referring to the same class but not introducing new types. I've add example to demonstrate the situation.